# Create Columns via Formula for two dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

How do you do this with columns instead of rows?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&DATEVALUE("2018-4-13")&
                               ":A"&DATEVALUE("2018-4-30"))), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
*(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/143247/create-columns-via-formula-for-two-dates/143249?noredirect=1#comment130834_143249))*

> *...to include a **custom start and end date** which I know I didn't ask for based on your reply*

```
=SEQUENCE(1,B2-A2,A2,1)
```

[image: create a sequence of dates using starting and end dates from cells]

---

Please use the following formula:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,18,"2018-4-13",1)
```

[image]

More about [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you! I modified the sequence to include a custom start and end date which I know I didn't ask for based on your reply.  

=arrayformula(text(sequence(1,cell_with_end _date - cell_with_start_date,cell_with_start_date,1),"mm/dd/yyyy"))

Comment: I think you over-complicate things. Please check the updated answer.